# Firebase Remote Config Fails on WiFi network in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-remote-config

Firebase Remote Config keeps throwing this error when mobile device is connected to my home WiFi network. Because of that data of Firebase Remote Config is not loaded in the app.

```
[log] [firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error
       #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
       #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #2      MethodChannelFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate (package:firebase_remote_config_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_remote_config.dart:150:29)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #3      FirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate (package:firebase_remote_config/src/firebase_remote_config.dart:90:26)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #4      setupRemoteConfigSettings (package:multiplapp/main.dart:77:5)
       <asynchronous suspension>
       #5      main (package:app_name/main.dart:28:3)
       <asynchronous suspension>
```

It works fine when mobile is connected to mobile data. I don't seem to understand what could be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated! Tried looking for similar issues on GitHub and stackoverflow but couldn't find one.

Comment: Have you found any solution? My guess would first check if wifi is properly working like the internet is actually working in your home wifi network, it happens sometimes when it is connected to a mobile but the internet is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[log] [firebase_remote_config/internal] internal remote config fetch error
```

if you got this problem then use  another internet connection (mobile), when you connected  another internet(,mobile data usage hotspot) then  restart your vs code,android code ,also your emulator ,then start your emulator . it will be working .

Comment: Welcome. English language only please.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing right now and it works but it's tedious process.